# asterisk Dial-plan?

Tags: asterisk

I want to make a dial plan for asterisk to do this:
for incoming-call check the caller-id and if caller id is equal with specific number (for example 666) then hangup that call.(`this dial-plan also known as anti ex-girlfriend` )

also I wrote this dial-plan for doing this but it doesn't work well.(don't hangup then incoming call from 666 and go to queue macro)

```
[macro-queue]
exten => s, 2, Queue(${ARG1})

[default]
exten => s, 1, Answer
exten => s/666, 2 ,Hangup
exten => s, 2, BackGround(welcome)
exten => s, 3, Macro(queue,operator)
```